# FlxButtonPlus not responding to anything inside of game's pause menu

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

I am using the haxeflixel game framework to create a game and I was making a pause menu. I tried using the default FlxButton but the collision with the mouse never lined up properly. So I tried using FlxButtonPlus because it had some cool hooks but the button will not respond to any inputs. here is my code declaring the button in the pause menu
`final unpausebut = new FlxButtonPlus((FlxG.width / 2) - 80,(FlxG.height / 2) - 10,unpause,"unpause",48,16); unpausebut.loadButtonGraphic(buttonNormal,buttonHovered); add(unpausebut);`
Here is a picture of the pause menu itself so far.

[image: A picture of the pause menu in game (zoomed in using paint.net)]

but the button doesn't seem to respond to anything. I am also getting no errors inside of the terminal. unpause is a function inside of the code that also closes the substate. Can anybody help?